# Trying to use the if function in Excel with a date and a number

Tags: excel

I have a spreedsheet and need want to have a cell light up with a green dot if:

1. one cell adds to 12 and
2. is by a certain date and
3. if the number does not add to 12 by the same date I need the cell to have a red X.

My questions is how to I add those 2 formulas for the same cell with red or green?

Comment: Do you mean you need the cell's background color to change to green or red?  I'm not sure what you mean by a "green or red dot"

Comment: I've revised your tag on this question. "Database" is meaningless in this context.

Comment: what if the date is not met yet? in the question, only the sum(12) has an impact - start with laying out all combinations in a grid, it will help you figure out all the needed outcomes and relevant conditions

Answer (score 0):

step 1 - create the `IF` statement so the recipient cell contains `X or O` depending of the condition being met or not

step 2 - create a conditional formatting depending of the content of the cell (X or O)

let me know if I need to elaborate with the actual formula.

Hint: check the `AND()` Excel function

Thank you